# How to make appear ONLY the characters from array onkeyup in html tag?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I need solution only in plain JavaScript for this project I can not use jQuery**

Ok ,so I have an html tag

`<p id="entry"> Your guesses so far: </p>`

I have an array with letters

`var alphabet = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h" , "i" , "j" , "k" , "l" , "m" , "n" , "o" , "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" , "u" , "v" , "w" , "x" , "y" , "z"];`

When I use `document.onkeyup = function(event) {.....}` I want only the letters that are in array appear in my html tag nothing else!

This is what I have so far

`document.onkeyup = function(event) {
        var userGuess = event.key.toLowerCase();
        entry.innerHTML += userGuess;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition before concatenating to the `<p>` element.

```
    var alphabet = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h" , "i" , "j" , "k" , "l" , "m" , "n" , "o" , "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" , "u" , "v" , "w" , "x" , "y" , "z"];

    document.onkeyup = function(e) {
        entry.innerHTML += ((alphabet.indexOf(e.key.toLowerCase()) > -1) ? e.key.toLowerCase() : '');
    }
```

Quick demo here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chbLuk3b/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
const alphabet = new Set(["a" , "b" , "c" , "d"]);

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  let userGuess = event.key.toLowerCase();

  if (alphabet.has(userGuess))
    entry.innerHTML += userGuess;
}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use Set?

Comment: @shuangwhywhy - It's not *necessary*, it's just *convenient*. (Assuming you don't care about older browser support, otherwise it is less convenient...)

Comment: @nnnnnn. So why not just use array `const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and `if (alphabet.includes(userGuess))`, which is even more convenient?

Comment: @shuangwhywhy - the `.includes()` method isn't supported in IE either. But you could use `.indexOf() != -1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try or tweak with below code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="entry" onkeyup="checkValue(this)" onblur="checkValue(this)"/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkValue(entry) {
        var text = entry.value;
        if (!text.match(/^[a-z]*$/)) {
            entry.value = text.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

It also handles

*Copy Content From Somewhere  >>  Right Click on Text Box >> Press Paste From Context pop-up menu*

If you want more restricted input character set, try to update the [regular expression.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

*Note: I have tested this code in Chrome browser only.*